# How can I use withRouter with forwardRef in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, ref

withRouter does not let me pass ref to a component, so I'm trying to create a HOC that will let me do that. I've tried to follow a few answers on stackoverflow and this is what I have now -

```html
export const withRouterForwardRef = <ComposedComponentProps extends {}>(ComposedComponent: ComponentClass<ComposedComponentProps>) => {
    type ComposedComponentInstance = InstanceType<typeof ComposedComponent>;
    type  WrapperComponentProps = ComposedComponentProps & {
        forwardedRef:Ref<ComposedComponentInstance>;
    };
    const WithRouter = withRouter(({ forwardedRef,...props }) => (
      <Component ref={forwardedRef} {...props} />
    ));
        
    return forwardRef((props, ref) => (
       <WithRouter {...props} forwardedRef={ref} />
    ));
  };
```

But here the forwardedRef in the withRouter throws an error saying - "***Property 'forwardedRef' does not exist on type 'RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, UnknownFacade> & { children?: ReactNode; }'.***"

Pretty much stuck here right now. Is there a better method to pass ref through withRouter?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use [wrappedComponentRef](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md#wrappedcomponentref-func) property to pass the ref to the underlying component:

```ts
export const withRouterForwardRef = <ComposedComponentProps extends {}>(ComposedComponent: ComponentClass<ComposedComponentProps>) => {
    type ComposedComponentInstance = InstanceType<typeof ComposedComponent>;
    type  WrapperComponentProps = ComposedComponentProps & {
        forwardedRef:Ref<ComposedComponentInstance>;
    };
    const WithRouter = withRouter(Component);
        
    return forwardRef((props, ref) => (
       <WithRouter {...props} wrappedComponentRef={ref} />
    ));
  };
```